# Fetch value by index in excel by apache poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi

i am trying to develop a desktop app and using excel as database.
Writing code for login and logout for a particular user who uses the desktop app but unable to do so.

what i am trying to achieve is that i have two columns in excel sheet like

`Username | Password
   A     |  a
   B     |  b
   C     |  c`

A is username and 'a' is password so what i have done so far is that i have comapred the value of A to the value user has entered and where it is matching i am fatching row and column index.

So that i can fetch my password residing next to it. For ex
A has row and column index 0,0
So the password will be at index 0,1

I dont know how to fetch value by index.
My code:

```
if(m1.equals(cell.getStringCellValue())){
 index=cell.getRowIndex();
 indexc=cell.getColumnIndex();
 System.out.println(index+" "+indexc);
 String s3=cell.getStringCellValue();
 if(m2.equals(?????????????)){
  // index2=cell.getRowIndex();
 counter=1;   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
public boolean checkCredentials(String userName, String password, Sheet credentialsSheet) {
        //Assuming username is in column1 and password is in column2 
        int usernameColumnNo = 0;
        int passwordColumnNo =1;
        Boolean isCredentialCorrect = false;
        for(Row row:credentialsSheet) {
            if(row.getCell(usernameColumnNo).getStringCellValue().equals(userName)){
isCredentialCorrect = row.getCell(passwordColumnNo).getStringCellValue().equals(password);
                break;
            }
        }
        return isCredentialCorrect;
    }
```